# AWS EC2: Is the "running" state sufficient for successfully sshing into ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I trying to ssh and run some command into ec2. For that I start the ec2 instance and eventually the `Instance state` comes in `running` state but the `Status Check` tab still shows `initializing`. So can I ssh in my ec2 at this point when `Instance state` is `running` but  `Status Check` is still `initializing`.

I did check this and I could ssh. But should I wait for the `Status Check` to be something else?

Comment: When it's allowing you to ssh what else could be a better check that it's ready for doing ssh?

Comment: If you want to run something when the instance immediately starts-up, you should pass the commands as a [User Data script](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html).

Comment: @JohnRotenstein but that is only for the first time an instance boots ups isn't it

Comment: If you want to run a script _every_ time that an instance starts, put the script in `/var/lib/cloud/scripts/per-boot/`. See: [Auto-Stop EC2 instances when they finish a task - DEV Community](https://dev.to/aws/auto-stop-ec2-instances-when-they-finish-a-task-2f0i)